# how to change content of bigPlayButton in video js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I'm showing the `big play button` after my video has `ended`. The `content` property of `big play button` is `\e001`. I want replace the content with my own custom icon. I want to use these [font-awesome](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/) icons so that I could use the replay icon. Is there a way to accomplish this by using a the `ended` event in javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user904861's answer seems mostly correct to me, except:

1. you may need to show the big play button upon 'ended' unless your version of videojs is already doing that.
2. i don't think the replay icon is included in the videojs compiled font, so you'll need to include FontAwesome and specify the font-family in your class.

So you'll need to include

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And then do something like:

```
myPlayer.on("ended", function() {
  myPlayer.bigPlayButton.show()
  $(".vjs-big-play-button:before").css("content", "\f01e");
  $(".vjs-big-play-button:before").css("font-family", "FontAwesome");
});
```

See a working example at: http://jsbin.com/uqukot/10/edit

Answer (score 1):

Look up the unicode of the Font Awesome icon on http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/.

Then you can override the play button on the `ended` event:

```
myPlayer.on("ended", function() {
  $(".vjs-big-play-button:before").css("content", "\f01e");
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but I want to do this after the video ends, so I want to know how i can use jquery/javascript to change the content on `ended` event.

Comment: Does it answer your question now?

Comment: no, I had tried this before, but this will try to search for class named ".vjs-big-play-button:before" which is not present in DOM. I guess the issue has to do with targeting pseudo elements which doesn't work in this way.